# How to assign weight to variables in random forests

Tags: random-forest, weights

I want to group similar variables at terminal nodes of the tree by assigning some weights to variables in random forests. What will be the effect of these weights on the model? More importantly, could you provide me suggestions on how to specify such weights and proceed further with analysis.

Comment: This question is too short. Please expand it and document some preliminary research.

Comment: Does it make sense now?

Comment: Yes, and I edited it somewhat further. Can you specify which package you are using and add some pertinent code?

Comment: Actually, I am using SPM which dont need code just UI. I know that what weight does it as it is either required at split and either at the leaf nodes. I want to learn about weighted random forest with weights specifically. Because i want my highest values at leaf nodes and how random forest give weight to each variable.